# NSImage drawInRect is more than 10 times slower on a much faster MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, cocoa

The time NSImage drawInRect call takes for the same image on a much newer/faster MacBook Pro is at least ten times more than an older MacBook Pro!

Both MacBooks are running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

**Newer/Faster MacBook:**
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019), 2.6GHz Intel Core i7, 16GB 2400 MHz DDR4, Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

**Older/Slower MacBook:**
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014), 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3, Graphics: Intel Iris 1536 MB

Here's the call that we're comparing:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

[self.myImage drawInRect:bounds fromRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.myImage.size.width, self.myImage.size.height) operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];

NSLog(@"Draw Image Time Taken: %f", -timeInterval);
```

The above method of time measurement isn't the best, but once you put the draw call in a loop to make the measured interval longer it does give us a clear idea.

You can download the Xcode project here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/test-image-drawing/TestImageDrawing.zip

Here's another Xcode project that demonstrates this:
https://storage.googleapis.com/test-image-drawing/TestImageDrawing1.zip

Here's a screenshot on slower/older MacBook along with the system configuration:
[image]

Here's a screenshot on newer/faster MacBook along with the system configuration:
[image]

Time taken for draw call on faster MacBook is usually around 0.002 whereas on slower MacBook is 0.0001!

It would be great if someone can throw some light on why this is happening and how this can be fixed.

**Update:**
Here's what Apple Technical Support says: This could be related to the different pixel depths on the two different monitors.  Wide colour support is relatively new and what may be being performed in hardware on the older machine may be involve a CPU based color conversion operation on the newer machine.  Some aspects of this (including ways you can optimize your content for new displays) are discussed in the followng video:

WWDC 2017 - Session 821:  Get Started with Display P3
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/821/

Still what code do I need to add, to fix this on the newer machines?

Comment: Heavily loaded ?

Comment: These times are short enough that it could be some kind of artifact, clock resolution, who knows what.  Draw in a loop a million times and see what the times look like then, I would say.

Comment: @ColdSteel By heavily loaded I meant with strong configurations; I didn't mean running a lot of tasks. I have corrected this ambiguity now.

Comment: @bhaller I have tried that as well and the result is the same. The newer MacBook runs the NSImage drawInRect more than 10 times slower.

Comment: @AmaltasCoder: You shouldn't be using `NSDate` as your timer, use `CFTimeInterval` instead. As mentioned the method you have chosen as a test gauge is not a very good indicator of why it would be faster/slower; you would need to profile your app in order to fully understand what is at work here.

Comment: Please focus on the real question at hand, the above method of time measurement isn't the best, but once you put the draw call in a loop to make the measured interval longer it does give us a clear idea. The real question is - why is NSImage drawInRect more than 10 times slower on a newer/faster MacBook Pro.

Comment: Did you profile your app?